# Can related sequence name be extracted from SQLAlchemy model's column?

Tags: python, postgresql, orm, sqlalchemy

Let's take simple example SQLAlchemy model:

```
class Organization(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'organization'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    # ... and so on...
```

In this case, when on PostgreSQL, as `id` is the primary key, this model will result with a sequencer creation, called `organization_id_seq`.

Is there any possibility to extract somehow this auto-generated sequencer name (or maybe other sequencer details, too) from the field this sequencer was created for (`Organization.id`) or from `Organization` class itself? Or maybe the only way is to "manually" check it in the db?

The motivation is not to hardcode the sequencer name in sequencer resetting utility, that with the team we use in some of the tests.

Comment: An automatically created sequence for a primary key always consists of table name, column name and `seq` suffix separated by underscores.

Comment: Thanks, that would ease things up. Is it something that one take for granted regardless of Postgres version or it's just some implementation detail that might be subject to change?

Comment: Well, I've been working with Postges for years and it has always been this way. I do not see any reasons why someone would like to change it. On the other hand however, it is not formally documented, as far as I know

Comment: Good to know. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found that way: init metadata, reflect particular table than iterate over all constraints and found one that you need.

```
from model import Model
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
m = MetaData()
m.reflect(Model.query.session.bind, only=[Model.__tablename__])
table_constraints = m.tables[Model.__tablename__].constraints
for constr in table_constraints:
    # checking isinstance(constr, PrimaryKeyConstraint) can be added
    for col in c.columns.values():
        if col.server_default is not None and col.server_default.arg is not None:
            print c.server_default.arg
            # prints nextval('table_id_seq'::regclass)
```

UPD.
Version allows to get sequence name for particular column without iteration:

```
from model import Model
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
m = MetaData()
m.reflect(Model.query.session.bind, only=[Model.__tablename__])
sequence_name = Model.id.server_default.arg.text
```

Comment: It might be a good direction. In my case `col.server_default` is None, though, but I only did a brief check. I'll dig into it and try to make it work tomorrow.

Comment: It may be default if you not specified it onto column definition. `Metadata().reflect()` retrieves DDL from DBMS: full table structure, indexes, constraints, triggers and so on. If you specify just `primary_key=True` for postgresql table's column, sqla generates `serial` type for it. After it Postgresql assigns to it some sequence.

Comment: You were right, the metadata I tried yesterday was not reflected correctly. It's working. However, I think the easier and a bit more elegant way (without looping over all table's constraints) to get this final text `nextval('table_id_seq'::regclass)` is `m.tables[Model.__tablename__].columns['id'].server_default.arg.text`. If you found this modification of your code appriopriate I think you could update the answer and I will accept it. Thanks for the effort!

Comment: You right, but just for your case. My version is more wide. Updated anyway :)